# When is $f^! \mathcal{O}_Y$ a line bundle?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $f: X \to Y$ be a finite, surjective morphism of reduced, separated schemes of finite typer over some field of characteristic zero. The sheaf $\mathcal{H}om_Y(f_* \mathcal{O}_X, \mathcal{O}_Y)$ is a coherent $f_* \mathcal{O}_X$-module and thus it corresponds to a coherent $\mathcal{O}_X$-module denoted by $f^! \mathcal{O}_Y$.

What are conditions on $f$, $X$ or $Y$ such that $f^! \mathcal{O}_Y$ is a line bundle on $X$? (e.g. $f$ is flat, $Y$ is smooth, etc.)

I think if $X$ and $Y$ are both smooth, then this is the case. And I guess that it is not true in general (does someone have a reasonable counter example?).

Comment: I think $f^{*}\mathcal{O}_{X}$ should be $f_{*}\mathcal{O}_{X}$ in your definition of the $f_{*}\mathcal{O}_{X}$-module.

Comment: that's correct. thx

Comment: So the question you're asking is completely local and is hence equivalent to asking when $\mathrm{Hom}_{R}(S, R)$ is a projective $S$-module (when $S$ is a finite $R$-algebra, $S$ and $R$ are finitely generated reduced algebras in characteristic $0$). I thought I had managed to show that this is equivalent to $S$ being projective over $R$ but I found some mistakes in my argument so I'm not sure anymore.

Comment: thx for your efforts. I think equivalence is not true: Let $S=k[T]$ amd $R=k[T^2,T^3]$. Then $S$ is not projective over $R$ but $\textrm{Hom}_R(S,R)$ is torsion-free and thus free since $S$ is a principal ideal domain.

Comment: Maybe this helps you somehow. Have a look at *Qing Liu - Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves* Proposition 6.4.25 where you see that $f^!\mathcal{O}_Y = \mathcal{H}om_{\mathcal{O}_Y}(f_* \mathcal{O}_X, \mathcal{O}_Y)$ is the $0$-dualizing sheaf for $f$. A short question from me: How does $f^!\mathcal{O}_Y$ correspond to an $\mathcal{O}_X$-module? I don't see that.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Regarding your question: Let $S$ be an $R$-algebra and $f: S\to R$ be a homomorphism of $R$-modules. Then we define $s\cdot f$ to be the homomorphism $x\mapsto f(sx)$.